# Kafka docker fail to start using spotify

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spotify

I am trying to setup Apache kafka in docker on my local windows machine. I am using the Spotify kafka image. Below is the docker command:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 
--env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.99.100
--env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
 spotify/kafka
```

The kafka image is getting downloaded and could see zookeeper has started and entered Running state but kafka server failed to start and gives a message

> kafka entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

below is the logs:

```
$ docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.99.100 --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file
 in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configu
ration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2018-10-30 07:29:27,733 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2018-10-30 07:29:27,733 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2018-10-30 07:29:27,734 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2018-10-30 07:29:27,744 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2018-10-30 07:29:27,745 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2018-10-30 07:29:27,746 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2018-10-30 07:29:28,749 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2018-10-30 07:29:28,755 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2018-10-30 07:29:29,563 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-10-30 07:29:30,566 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2018-10-30 07:29:30,569 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 249
2018-10-30 07:29:30,838 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-10-30 07:29:32,844 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 471
2018-10-30 07:29:33,150 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-10-30 07:29:36,158 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 693
2018-10-30 07:29:36,452 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-10-30 07:29:37,454 INFO gave up: kafka entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your command

Comment: yeah, i reran it again but every time i get the same error mentioned in description

Comment: The Spotify image is so outdated (over 2 years ago). Please try https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/installation/index.html